# How to create in-house app store for iPad

Tags: iphone, app-store, updates, in-house-distribution

We are planning to create multiple apps for our different customers. For the distribution of the same, we are thinking if we can create an app-store of our own and ask the clients to get the apps from that space. Also, can I control the visibility of these apps so that client A doesn't see an app which is visible for client B?

Also, in such scenrios, how can I push updates of the application to the consumers?

I'm not sure, if this falls in Enterprise Distribution as the application is not within the company boundaries but for an external audience.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
~Vishal

Comment: This is not Google, have you tried looking for info about this? (Spoiler Alert: It's not possible on the iPhone)

Comment: I'm sorry, if this doesn't fit this forum. I have explored a lot on google but with no answers.

Comment: Strictly speaking, StackOverflow is not a forum. But I realize that's being pedantic. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow in-house App stores for distributing apps to other than the employees of an Enterprise enrolled iOS Developer.  Thus in-house App stores can not be used for an external audience.

Ad Hoc deployment is limited to 100 devices per year, so is probably unsuitable for this as well.

The alternatives are to have each customer enroll as an Enterprise developer under their own name, and create their own app store behind their own employee-only firewall; or for you to try and distribute the apps in Apple's public App store, which means that downloading can not be restricted to only particular clients.

Comment: Thanks hotpaw2. Apple has come up with a VPP program where organisation can buy applications in bulk from the app-store and the suplier can then do customization of these apps. Though I couldn't get much info on these